# Pimcore partial navigation parameter

Tags: zend-framework, pimcore

I have this basic pimcore partial based navigation:

```php
// see https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Documents/Navigation.html
$mainNavStartNode = $this->document->getProperty("mainNavStartNode");
$mainNavigation = $this->pimcoreNavigation($this->document, $mainNavStartNode, null, null, true);

$partial = 'includes/navigations/partials/main-navigation.php';
echo $mainNavigation->menu()->setPartial($partial)->setUlClass('')->setUseTranslator(false)->render($mainNavigation->getContainer());
```

Now I want to pass some params to the partial view but can't find anything about this in the docs...

Answer (score 0):

Assign some view params in some controller, probably best would be Action Controller.

```
$this->view->param = getSomeParams();
```

Now `var $this->param` will be available from your partial menu template.

I hope this will help.

Best Regards

Comment: Your right, that could be one possible way but I think it's not that smart... Isn't there any way to pass params to the render function?

Comment: I tried it in my controller with setting a view param but I can't access it inside of the partial... It's always null..